# Saving data without database?

Tags: php, database, server, sails.js

I'm writing a PHP/HTML app that I want to compile to a windows app with no need for a browser (with `ExeOutput` for example).

Well, my dad works in prison, so he has internet connection but he can't access to a lot of sites because the browser does not allow him to (again, I am saying what he tells me, I don't know how if they "don't allow him"). So he asked to make this app portable.

The thing is... it is an app that it should save everything he does. It has a total hours, and it has inputs with the hours he does every day, and it displays a "dot" on a calendar on the days he has added some hours, plus those hours has to be subtracted from the total.

It will have a button to "save" and next time he accesses the app, all the hours he has changed last time, are loaded again.

Does this make any sense?

Well, at work, I work on the server, so I would create a table to save that data, but because it is not anything from work, once I've finished I can't use this server any more.

My question is whether there is any way I can save data without a database? Because I guess he won't have a database on his computer :S

Everything is still very abstract for me referring to programming, so maybe anything of what I've just said has sense.

I have read another post around here talking about `Sails.js`, but when I look the information it is not clear if it is what I am looking for. If anyone has an idea about what I am trying to achieve.... I would appreciate any help!

Comment: php runs server side so not your best choice

Comment: sqllite gives you a nice protable database :-)

Comment: @user3791372 ;  "You are not the best person for this..." : Everyone starts that way.

Comment: No, everyone starts with a question. A tangible question. If you're looking to make an application for your dad, php is immediately out of the question, and the rest of your story / lots of questions don't make sense!

Comment: @user3791372 I started doing it with php because it is what I do at work. At work, I have everything set up, and I know that I just have to add the credentials for our server. In my dad's work, yes, he can run portable apps (he does it with games... with something like all player to watch his films.... because their internet does not allow them. If I am asking for a way to do it without server is because of that, because I don't want to even thing I can mess up their server. Did you born learnt? ^^" So you said php is immediately out of question, why?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets thank you for replying :) I don't know if it is still possible what I am trying to do but I am going to check sllite :) thanks

Comment: Why is PHP immediately out? Choosing the right tool for the right job is important, and PHP is not it for this job despite it allowing you to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm., can't have the cake and eat it too, PHP cannot be converted into an exe. A close alternative, will be XAMPP, if he is allowed to install it in prison, the data will be local, you could develop in PHP and deploy it to his XAMPP folder. SQLite is ideal for small portable data keeping.

Python is super for this kind of thing, and you can convert it into a pretty portable application using Py2Exe. You can do the development at your end, choose to store data in say, JSON or XML or any other flat file database or portable database such as SQLite. I had a quick learning of Python for a similar simple app I wanted, and with the use of pre-built libraries for most common tasks, I found the experience good, as a beginner.

Plus 1, for a son who develops an app for a Dad, love you for that. :-)

Comment: On the last sentence: follow the link to the OP's profile page. :)

Comment: @MarkBannister : Oops, good catch, no gender bias intended, even more Plus 1 for a loving daughter. I don't look at profiles before answering, lest I let the profile influence my answer. :-) :-)

Comment: php can't be converted into an exe? :S oux :S I have read in a few places there are some software to do it, like ExeOutput... Exe-P... Bambalam PHP EXE... to be honest I haven't read the pages in details, I just supposed it was possible :S :S so those softwares are not for that?

Comment: @eve_mf :   Okay, had a look at ExeOutput, that's a new one to me. Even then, they don't mention portable. At best, it will require installation of the application. And then, they don't mention a thing about data or databases. That's probably for tasks with not much data.

Comment: well I was thinking to do it portable afterwards!

I have done it before with spoon studio. Actually, one of my teachers on my first year in a degree similar with an NVQ3 here, shown us this software and I remember I converted photoshop in portable, so I've though it can be done easily just using another software.

Comment: @eve_mf :  If you are looking at virtualization as an option, you could deploy the PHP web app on the cloud, with AWS or Google Cloud, if he is allowed to access such websites. I wouldn't do it, because cloud is costly for me, :-)

Comment: There's a portable version of XAMPP I believe.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use "Portable" database , SQLite , it is a file and could be included (embedded) in the project files, you can use PDO to access SQLite as you would do the same for MySQL

You can have a look at SQLite/PHP Example
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, but it's possible to use flatfile database.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database

Once again: it's not the best way, it might even be a really bad way, but it's possible.

But if it's PHP code I assume you still need PHP, even in .exe. Or will it be compiled that way?

Comment: uf! now I'm even more confused than before. I'm sorry.... 
So I start from the beginning. My dad wants a calendar (which I have done in php/html), and there are some functionality for that calendar. (add or subtract ours from the total, and in the day he does it, it appears a dot/image indicating that day has hours (adding or subtracting). I don't know how much he is not allow to access to pages (for example, he can not access to youtube -just an example-), but the only way he tells me it is that his internet is very restricted. I know some php, jquery/js and html.. can I do anything with it?

Comment: If you want it to work with PHP, he needs PHP. So he either needs something like WAMP/XAMPP (which has PHP so then database isn't a problem) or it has to be hosted elsewhere (which would also have PHP). Don't see the problem. 

If you're only using Javascript and HTML, he can run it via his own computer without a webhost, then you'd need JSON (as Ashish Choudhary said) or a flatfile database.

If I misunderstood you completely, I'm sorry. Just trying to help :)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but that's the thing. He can't install wamp in his computer, my dad is 60 years old! He hardly knows how to open a browser..... he is familiar with computers enough to add his time sheets and look for stuff on google, so I can't ask him to install WAMP. is that what you meant?

Comment: Nevermind, I saw you've already accepted an answer which is tbh much better :-)

Answer (score 1):

What so ever language you use. If you want to be database free, the best thing according to me will be to use JSON files. They are very light. They can store any amount of data. Their format is readable by any language(so you dont have to worry about web interface or desktop app). And its easy to learn. It Will take you only one hour to understand it :)

Comment: yes because a phone has of course unlimited storage space... and what if the app has 3 months of data in it? that'll be a huge json to parse and reflect and store.

Comment: Did i mentioned here that JSON needs to be stored in the phone only? DIdn't he said that they have internet connectitivty so that JSON files can be stored on any webserver whose address/ip is allowed.

Comment: Also its a different logic how to store JSON files. Maybe we can have a week's data in one file. I dont think so it will be much as its plain text. I have given the solution to the problem and not whole code/logic.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets : I guess, 'app' dint mean, phone app, it meant apps before phone apps came along.

Comment: yes yes sorry, as app I mean as application for windows. It is my first year programming so I don't know anything really :S and even if I read about.... sometimes I understand things in a wrong way :S